# Needed help to show these are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

How can we show that these two groups are isomorphic, $\mathbb Q^{\times}$ and $\mathbb Q_{\text{positive}}^{\times}\times\mathbb Z_2$. I don't know what to do with $\mathbb Z_2$. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth checking that $\mathbb Q^{\times}_{>0}$ is a group first: this is immediate from $\mathbb Q^{\times}$ being a group and that positive times positive is positive. Clearly then $\mathbb Q^{\times} = \mathbb Q^{\times}_{>0} \times \mathbb Z/(2)$ - the $\mathbb Z/(2)$ just keeps track of the sign.

I assume $\mathbb Q^{+}$ should be $\mathbb Q^{\times}$. If so the problem is resolved. If not the answer should be negative because $\mathbb Q^{+}$ has no torsion but $\mathbb Q^{\times}$ does (1 and -1).

Comment: Yes it is $\times$ in the power

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try this map:  $x\to (|x|,sign(x))$ where $sign(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $sign(x)=-1$ if $x<0$